# Unable to get jQuery on() to register dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, function, delegates, live

I'm quite new to the on() method in jQuery but the time has come for me to need to use it.

I've two functions for clicking on specific buttons. Each function works on any elements originally on the page but not on any dynamically added content (more of the same buttons). I understand I need to use the on() function after reading other answers on here and on Google but am having trouble still. Anyway, code:

```
jQuery("ul#THEBUTTONS").on({
    click: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("apaz clicked");
    }
}, "a.azaz");


jQuery("ul#THEBUTTONS").on({
    click: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("mapaz clicked");
    }
}, "a.mapaz");
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated, tearing my hair out here.

Comment: Is the `#THEBUTTONS` element an ancestor of your dynamic `<a>` elements?

Comment: So the element #THEBUTTONS is a static ancestor of your dynamically added `<a>`elements? Are you sure it's "a.azaz" and not "a.apaz"? Try `.on('click', 'a.azaz', function(event) {...})` instead ... more people are used to this invokation style

Comment: your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tSUg7/ , maybe it's the html ?

Comment: It's an ancestor but thinking about it, it's also dynamically inserted... which would mean I need to go higher up than that right? Also @A.B.Cade, thanks, it does work, but not on a dynamically created element.

Comment: Interestingly if the container selector goes any higher than the content I've dynamically added, so even like, body, then it just ceases to work.

Comment: @Tristan, do you obtain better results if you delegate the event to the document itself? `jQuery(document).on(...);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.on()` essentially has two flavors: one which acts like `.bind()`, and another which acts like `.delegate()`.

For your problem, you want to use the `delegate` version. As a reference, `on` signatures are like this:

```
// bind
$(element-selector).on(event, handler)

// delegate
$(container-selector).on(event, element-selector, handler)
```

The best way to get up to speed with this is probably [to read up on `delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), what it is, how its used, and then apply that to `on`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Again this (and therefore what @Anthony Grist suggested too) only serves to make the original elements clickable. If it's any help I'm grabbing the element out of somewhere else with the .html() method and re-inserting it elsewhere.

Comment: Interestingly if the container selector goes any higher than the content I've dynamically added, so even like, body, then it just ceases to work.

Comment: If you're grabbing just the HTML, then the event handlers you've attached to those elements don't get carried over with it. You'd do better to use `$().clone(true,true)` instead, or to slap the new elements inside a container where you've assigned the `delegate` command.

Comment: That did it! I don't know how to express my gratitude Richard! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use `.on()`, and you're using the wrong type.

You can bind event handlers directly to elements using `$('selector for elements you want the event handler bound to').on('event', function() {...});`

Or, you can delegate events, by calling `.on()` on a wrapper element that will contain all of the dynamically added elements, such as a div or, in the worst case, the `<body>` element. Code would look something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="link">Test link</a>
</div>

$('#wrapper').on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    // code to handle the click event on the link here
});
```

The event handler is actually handled by the `<div id="wrapper">` element once the event has bubbled up to it, but the function is only called if the original target matches the selector provided. With this method, you can dynamically add additional elements with the class `link` to the div, and the function will also run when they're clicked on.

Comment: The questioner is registering a handler map, not a single handler, so `on(eventMap, selector)` is the right form to use.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good point, apparently I didn't read the question thoroughly enough.