# jQuery not finding iframe elements in Firefox or IE < 8?

Tags: jquery, firefox, element, selector

I have an iframe on my page that is dynamically loaded when a link is clicked (a lightbox). As soon as that lightbox opens, and the iframe content has loaded, i need to insert some content to the iframe.

It works great in all browsers except for Firefox.

```
console.log( $('.fancybox-inner iframe').contents().find('html .clearinputtext').length );
```

returns 0 in firefox. It's suppose to return 4.

Any ideas? I'm running Firefox v16.

EDIT: Actually, it also doesn't work in ie<8, but that's not very suprising.

Comment: You possibly want to look at the on() function. Have a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698936/unable-to-get-jquery-on-to-register-dynamically-added-content

Comment: Yeah going off Billy - are you firing this log after the 'load' event of the iframe has fired?

Comment: Something like: `$('.fancybox-inner iframe').contents().find('.clearinputtext').on('load', function() { Do something });` ?

Comment: @AaronRomine Yes, i am! It's called on the afterShow eventhandler, so the content has already been loaded and displayed before this code is run.

Comment: Just a note, you can condense `.find('html').find('.clearinputtext')` to `.find('html .clearinputtext');`

Comment: @Adam Ah, you're right, of course! I'll change it, but i doubt that caused the bug.

Comment: It didn't cause the issue, I tested it. But just makes it more readable (:

Comment: Alright then. Any ideas what's causing this? I'm not seeing how .on() would help, since the content has already been loaded and displayed when i try to find the elements. I see the elements very clearly, i can even inspect them frm the DOM, i just can't get them with javascript!?

Comment: you shouldn't need to specify "html" to find the el with the given class, have you tried without it? What version of jQuery?

Comment: No i haven't tried that yet, i'll give it a shot as soon as i can! I believe i'm using 1.7.something. Haven't updated due to some compatibility issues.