# jQuery - How to make .on event work for dynamically created HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event, jquery-on

Reading up on the New specs for the newest jQuery 1.x library, it says to use `.on` to attach events that work for dynamically created jQuery elements, however, I can't seem to get this work at all.  In my `$(document).ready` function I have the following:

jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).text() == '[ Read more... ]' ? 'expand' : 'collapse';
    var theDiv = type == 'expand' ? $(this).parent().next("div") : $(this).parent().prev("div");
    var theId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var vText = theId == 'reqMat' ? 'Every candidate is required to submit a headshot and candidate statement.' : 'To strengthen your candidacy and let people know what you\'re all about, we invite you to create a campaign video.';

    theDiv.animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500, function(){
        if (type == 'expand')
            theDiv.after('<p class="desc"><a href="#" class="dropdown" id="' + theId + '">[ Collapse Information... ]</a></p>');
        else
            theDiv.before('<p class="desc">' + vText + ' <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="' + theId + '">[ Read more... ]</p>');

        if (theId == 'optMat' && type == 'expand')
        {
            var sVidWidth = $("#sampleVideo").width();
            $("#sampleVideo").css({'height': (sVidWidth/1.5) + 'px'});
        }
        else if (theId == 'optMat' && type == 'collapse')
        {
            var iframe = $('#sampleVideo')[0];
            var player = $f(iframe);
            player.api('pause');
        }

        if (theId == 'reqMat' && type == 'expand')
        {
            handleBullets();
        }
    });
});
```

Ok, so this will drop down the `[ Read more... ]` text and turn it into a `[ Collapse Information... ]` string that will go underneath of the actual content that is being expanded.  But when I click on the `[ Collapse Information... ]` text, it doesn't collapse anything, instead it goes to the top of the page, thus having an `href="#"`, but using `.on` should prevent that from happening when the `event.preventDefault();` is applied correct??

Am using the jQuery library found here:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

My HTML is laid out like so, if this even matters:

```
<h4>Header 1</h4>
<p class="desc">Brief description. <a href="#" id="reqMat" class="dropdown">[ Read more... ]</a></p>
<div style="display: none;">
    <p>More information is in here...</p>
</div>
<h4>Header 2</h4>
<p class="desc">Brief description. <a href="#" id="optMat" class="dropdown">[ Read more... ]</a></p>
<div style="display: none;">
    <p>More information is in here...</p>
</div>
```

The first time I click it, it works, but the 2nd time, when `[ Collapse Information... ]` is shown it doesn't work at all.  So it is not attaching itself to the dynamically created `<p class="desc"><a href="#" class="dropdown" id="' + theId + '">[ Collapse Information... ]</a></p>`.

Why not?  Is there something else I should be using instead of `.on`?  I know that `.live` is no longer used since jQuery 1.7.  `.click` will not work either as I have already tried that as well.  What other options are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to get jQuery on() to register dynamically added content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698936/unable-to-get-jquery-on-to-register-dynamically-added-content)

Answer (score 3):

To get the `on` method to register a delegate event handler (just as the `delegate` method does), you need to specify a selector for the element, and apply it to an element that already exist.

For example:

```
$("body").on("click", ".dropdown", function(event) {
```

Preferably, you should apply it to a parent element as close as possible to the dynamically added elements rather than `"body"`, to reduce the scope as much as possible. Otherwise the selector `".dropdown"` needs to be evaluated for every click that happens in the page. Typically you would use the containing element that you add the dynamic content to.

Comment: Nice, but this does not work in IE9 and below.  What happens in IE9 and below is as follows:  Clicking on `[ Read more... ]` link expand it down, clicking on `[ Collapse Link... ]` collapses it up as it should, but than clicking on `[ Read more... ]` link again, stops after doing this part of the script:  `$(this).parent().remove();`.  The whole point of using jQuery is so that it works cross-browser.  This is not true!

Comment: Nevermind, figured out the problem in IE, was missing a closing `</a>` tag.  Doopppee!

Comment: I did $(document).on("change",".searchFields",function(event){} and worked like a charm! I was having problems because I didn't use $(document).on, I was saying $(".searchFields").on which if you dynamically insert html with that class will NOT work, but my solution does.  Hope this helps someone.