# How to access an <li> after removing it, and then adding it back again?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I remove an `<li>` by clicking on a `delete_it` div within it.

In the same action, I append an `<li>` to the end of the list:

```
$(".delete_it").on("click", function(e){
$(this).parent().remove();
$(".images_list").append("<li class=\"things\"><div class=\"crop_it\"></div><div class=\"delete_it\"></div></li>");
});
```

I have functionality linked to the `crop_it` div in the newly appended `<li>`, that is not working.

```
$(".crop_it").on("click", function(e){
// do things
});
```

No errors in Firebug.

I thought that by using `on`, newly added selectors would be available.

Is there anything I can do to somehow re-initalise or refresh the view so that the newly added item is accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
$(".crop_it").on("click", function(e) {
```

Use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".crop_it", function(e) {
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17778024/1063287

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Event delegation with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(".images_list").on("click",".delete_it", function(e){
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    $(".images_list").append("<li class=\"things\"><div class=\"crop_it\"></div><div class=\"delete_it\"></div></li>");
});
```

#### Same way do crop also

```
$(".images_list").on("click",".crop_it", function(e){
    // Do Cropping stuff here...
});
```